# Google App Script: LockService doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to implement a chat-bot using GAS (google app script). And faced some troubles with LockService. It seems not to work properly or at all.

When i get new message from appropriate chat, i saved delay-value (8 seconds) for ignoring subsequent messages from this chat. I do this using lockService to avoid skipping concurrent messages.

However it doesn't work, and some messages leaved out.

My code:

```
function get_message_safely(chat_id, message) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  const delay = 8*1000; // 8 seconds
  // save time of getting message
  var get_time = (new Date()).getTime();

  // lock
  // set lock before accessing data

    try {
      if (lock.hasLock()) { // ==always false (for unknown reasons)
        sendLog('get_message_safely/hasLock', 'lock = true' + '\n' + message);
      }
      lock.waitLock(10000); // wait 10 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
    } catch (error) {
      sendLog('get_message_safely/lock_service',  'ОШИБКА: ' + error);
      send_message(chat_id,  "Наши сервера сейчас загружены. Отправьте сообщение повторно или попробуйте позже.");
      lock.releaseLock();
      return;
    }



  // get data from PropertiesService
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var chat_access_flag = scriptProperties.getProperty(chat_id);

  if (chat_access_flag != undefined) { // if chat already exist
    if (chat_access_flag == 'false') {  // access denied
      sendLog('get_message_safely/lock_service',  'LockService: доступ запрещен.\n' + message);
      lock.releaseLock();
      return;
    } 
    var lock_time = Number(chat_access_flag);
    if (get_time <= lock_time) { // access denied: lock_time is still actual
      sendLog('get_message_safely/lock_service',  'LockService: доступ запрещен т.к. время не прошло:\n' + lock_time + ' - ' + get_time + ' = ' + (lock_time - get_time) +  '\n' + message);
      lock.releaseLock();
      return;
    }
    sendLog('get_message_safely/lock_service',  'LockService: доступ разрешен:\n' + lock_time + ' - ' + get_time + ' = ' + (lock_time - get_time) + '\nnew_lock_time: ' + (get_time + delay) + '\n' + message);
  }

  scriptProperties.setProperty(chat_id, get_time + delay);     // if access is allowed, set new delay

  // lock release
  lock.releaseLock(); // release the lock

  get_message(chat_id, message); // handling message
}
```

So, sometimes i have the case (when i send a lot messages at the same time), when lockService should handle it but it doesn't:

Case (example):

```
// lock_time == a;
// get 1 message: access allowed. So set new value to lock_time (=b)
// lock_time == b; 
// get 2 message: access denied. get_time < lock_time (=b)
// lock_time still == b;
// get 3 message: access allowed: get_time > lock_time, where lock_time == a (!???). So set new value to lock_time (=c);
// lock_time == с (??)
// get 4 message: access denied: get_time < lock_time (=b)
```

Handling messages due to lockService should be done sequentially. But some messages for some reason access to PropertiesService and get same date at same time.

It's blowing my mind. Have you any ideas what's happening here?
And how can i reach desirable result?

Comment: Hi @NikitaGoncharov! After studying your code I see that [`.hasLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#haslock) always returns `false`. In your scenario this could mean that neither [`.waitLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitlocktimeoutinmillis) nor [`.tryLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#trylocktimeoutinmillis) was called before. Could you please implement any of those methods and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

After studying your code I see that [`.hasLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#haslock) always returns `false`. Please, forgive me if I am mistaken. In your scenario this could mean that neither [`.waitLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitlocktimeoutinmillis) nor [`.tryLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#trylocktimeoutinmillis) was called before. To fix the issue you have to use one of the mentioned methods. You can read on the links some example usages. Please, ask me any question if you need further help.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. The main problem is described in my example (case). I use .hasLock() only for debagging. I thought if another instance of my script acquire the lock, then .hasLock() in current instance should be true (it would mean my lock doesn't work). But if misunderstood lock.hasLock() - it's not big deal, i think. My debag case is still actual, and i don't understand why. This is my main problem.

Comment: Why lockService in my case doesn't work and not put all simultaneous instances of my script in queue in this block of code. I set a new value in my ServiceProperties, but if 2 or more scripts executing in the same moment, they all get old value, when only first one should get old value and other should get updated value

Comment: When you says "*I set a new value in my ServiceProperties, but if 2 or more scripts executing in the same moment, they all get old value*" I understand that you are referring to the lines `  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); var chat_access_flag = scriptProperties.getProperty(chat_id);` If that is true, are you using different values for both `chat_id` or are you using the same one?

Comment: I use the same chat_id for messages from the same chat. My case is exactly about messages from same chat. So yes - same chat_id

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to call the method `.getScriptProperties()` from different users and get distinct values in return. If my assumption about your situation is correct, that operation isn't possible. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores) it is stated the `.getScriptProperties()` is shared among all the users of the same script. If you want different results from different users you can try using `.getUserProperties()`. Also could you please try to log the variable just after updating it to confirm if it really changed?

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I have common storage for all my script executions. My program is a chat bot. So when i get new message from a some chat, a set a delay into my storage (sctiprProps) by appropriate chat_id (so every chat have own delay value in this storage). So when i get new message from some chat, i save delay for this chat_id to ignore next messages from this chat for "delay" time (i my case it is 8 seconds). When next message from that chat comes, i check if delay time is left or not. (if not, message won't be handled). However, my program doesn't work properly in this situation.

Comment: In my case, new message is coming and we set delay (8 secs). Next message is coming, see delay is still actual and go off. Third message is coming,  check delay BUT there is another delay value, that had been there before 1-st message came. And this message go inside. And 4-th message comes, see delay and there is truly actual delay value, so message go off (as it should). BUT 3-rd message for some reasons wasn't be rejected, while should be.

Comment: I think the reason is rewriting my delay values by simultaneous executions due to incorrect work of LockSevice

Comment: Please forgive me for my misunderstanding. I couldn't reproduce the issue with your code. I strongly recommend logging the `.hasLock()` value with a timestamp every time that you interact with it, both before and after the interaction. This is to prevent any missed change on the variable. If you strongly believe that `LockService` is faulty, please write a minimal example that proves it so we all can study it better. Please, come back with your findings so I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for you time and your struggles to help me. Will be back when get smth